# Can I buff my Atronachs in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've taken to becoming a summoner in Skyrim and I focus mainly on summoning minions and reviving dead enemies to fight for me, though it doesn't seem that my Fire Atronach does much damage and dies very quickly, how can I use spells/perks to buff my minions to deal more damage/be more durable.

Comment: Would you consider followers as "summons"?  Plain magic summons are generally terrible.  It is mostly used as a throwaway decoy so you can hide/heal and fight.

That is until you get the Thrall daily power and use the crown to generate an army, but they tend to block you like no tomorrow.

Comment: @Nelson No, I tend to buff my followers using spells like Courage etc. but summoned monsters resist my heals/buffs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the vanilla game all conjuration summons have fixed stats and are unable to be buffed by your illusion magic*.  Higher tier atronach spells will result in a slightly stronger atronach (i.e. fire->frost->storm) as well the elemental potency perk in the conjuration tree.

However, there are many many atronach mods available on the PC that you can use to increase their use.  For example, [Atronach Scaling](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/57683/?) levels them up to match the player level.

*Taking the master of minds illusion perk will allow your illusion spells to affect your summons.  You are probably better off just getting our conjuration up instead and using higher level summons as it requires illusion at 90 to obtain.  I've played a pure summoner mage before and I haven't found many things that can handle an endless stream of dremora lords, especially when they appear 2 at a time.

Comment: Not sure why you put master of minds in a footnote—I think that’s the answer. I’m not the OP, but I have master of minds and never thought to try using it on my conjured daedra.

Comment: Yeah, +1 entirely for Master of the Mind, that's the answer.